# Fast calculation of many scalar products

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, cuda, parallel-processing

I have a program that calculates `1-10` million scalar products.

It looks like this. `ts` and `A` are arrays of about `1000`-`10000` 3D points (each element is a `3x1` vector). For the moment, with `ts.size() = 10,000` and `A.size() = 1000`, my code takes about `41ms`. I have not done any parallelization so far. Will the calculations be much faster, for example, in CUDA? I have no such experience. Or is there any other way? Thanks.

```
for(int i = 0; i< ts.size(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j< A.size(); j++){
        if(abs(scalarProduct(ts.at(i), A.at(j))) <epsilon){
            score[i] +=1;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my implementation of the scalar product.

```
double scalarProduct(const Point &p1,const Point &p2)
{
return (p1.getX()*p2.getX() + p1.getY()*p2.getY() + p1.getZ()*p2.getZ()) ;
}
```

Could I use Lapack or Eigen instead, formulating the problem as matrix multiplication? I've done that in Matlab and it is only `5` times slower. Any speedup would be great. With OpenMP i guess I could be `4x` faster.

Comment: did you enable optimisation? And the implementation of scalerProduct would be good to see. And what sizes/speed are you aiming for?

Comment: You could try to use OpenMP and see what kind of speed-up you'll get. It would be trivial to implement (I think you only need a `#pragma omp parallel for`). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP

Comment: DirectXMath has SIMD implementation for vector maths. You should definitely check it out!

Comment: Also platform/compiler would be interesting, maybe they already have a build-in parallel library

Comment: I made a silly mistake in my OpenMP suggestion. The result was correct but it was inefficient. I corrected my answer. The efficient solution is very simple. Just add `#pragma omp parallel for` before your outer loop.

Answer (score 4):

This answer consists of two parts:

1. Accelerating the calculation of many independent scalar products;
2. Solving your specific problem.

**PART 1**

The problem of calculating a large number of independent scalar products is an embarassingly parallel problem. If you aim at accelerating only the mentioned scalar products, retaining the rest of the computation on the CPU, then I agree with Calvin that most of the time will be spent in device-> memory transaction of the large `N*M` resulting matrix. However, if you purge your timing from the mentioned transaction, accelerating the calculations will be worth. This is shown by the code below, tested on an Intel Xeon E5-2650 2.00 GHz, Eight core processor equipped with an NVIDIA Kepler K20c cards, and whose timing is the following:

```
CPU: 27ms;     GPU (without D2H transaction): 0.08ms;     GPU (with D2H transaction): 23ms

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define BLOCKSIZE_X 16
#define BLOCKSIZE_Y 16

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

/*******************/
/* iDivUp FUNCTION */
/*******************/
int iDivUp(int a, int b) { return ((a % b) != 0) ? (a / b + 1) : (a / b); }

/*************************************************/
/* DEVICE FUNCTION PERFORMING THE SCALAR PRODUCT */
/*************************************************/
__host__ __device__ float scalarProduct(float p1x, float p1y, float p1z, float p2x, float p2y, float p2z)
{
    return (p1x * p2x + p1y * p2y + p1z * p2z) ;
}

/*******************/
/* KERNEL FUNCTION */
/*******************/
__global__ void kernel(const float* __restrict__ p1x, const float* __restrict__ p1y, const float* __restrict__ p1z, 
              const float* __restrict__ p2x, const float* __restrict__ p2y, const float* __restrict__ p2z, 
              float* __restrict__ output, const int N, const int M) {

    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int idy = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;

    if ((idx < N) && (idy < M))

        output[idy * N + idx] = scalarProduct(p1x[idx], p1y[idx], p1z[idx], p2x[idy], p2y[idy], p2z[idy]);

}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    const int N = 10000;
    const int M = 1000;

    // --- Host side allocations
    float *Ax = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
    float *Ay = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
    float *Az = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));

    float *Bx = (float*)malloc(M*sizeof(float));
    float *By = (float*)malloc(M*sizeof(float));
    float *Bz = (float*)malloc(M*sizeof(float));

    float *C = (float*)malloc(N*M*sizeof(float));
    float *D = (float*)malloc(N*M*sizeof(float));

    // --- Device side allocations
    float *d_Ax; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_Ax, N*sizeof(float)));
    float *d_Ay; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_Ay, N*sizeof(float)));
    float *d_Az; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_Az, N*sizeof(float)));

    float *d_Bx; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_Bx, M*sizeof(float)));
    float *d_By; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_By, M*sizeof(float)));
    float *d_Bz; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_Bz, M*sizeof(float)));

    float *d_C; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_C, N*M*sizeof(float)));

    // --- Initialization
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        Ax[i] = rand() / RAND_MAX;
        Ay[i] = rand() / RAND_MAX;
        Az[i] = rand() / RAND_MAX;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<M; i++) {
        Bx[i] = rand() / RAND_MAX;
        By[i] = rand() / RAND_MAX;
        Bz[i] = rand() / RAND_MAX;
    }

    // --- Host side computations
    double t1 = clock();
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) 
        for (int j=0; j<M; j++) 
            C[i*M + j] = scalarProduct(Ax[i], Ay[i], Az[i], Bx[j], By[j], Bz[j]);
    double t2 = clock();
    printf("CPU elapsed time: %3.4f ms \n", 1000.*((double)(t2-t1))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    // --- Device side computations
    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCKSIZE_X, BLOCKSIZE_Y);
    dim3 dimGrid(iDivUp(N, BLOCKSIZE_X), iDivUp(M, BLOCKSIZE_Y));

    float time;
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    // --- Host to device memory transfers
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_Ax, Ax, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_Ay, Ay, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_Az, Az, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_Bx, Bx, M*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_By, By, M*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_Bz, Bz, M*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // --- Computations
    kernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_Ax, d_Ay, d_Az, d_Bx, d_By, d_Bz, d_C, N, M);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(D, d_C, N*M*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("Elapsed time:  %3.4f ms \n", time);


    for (int i=0; i<N*M; i++) {
        if (D[i] != C[i]) {
            printf("Mismatch at i = %i; Host= %f, Device = %f\n", i, C[i], D[i]);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("Results match!\n");
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

**PART 2**

For solving your specific problem, the CUDA will be worth, even by considering the D2H memory transaction (which is very cheap). This is confirmed by the code below, tested on the same system as above, and whose timing is the following:

```
CPU: 46ms;     GPU (with D2H transaction): 0.31ms;

#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define BLOCKSIZE_X 16
#define BLOCKSIZE_Y 16

/********************/
/* CUDA ERROR CHECK */
/********************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

/*******************/
/* iDivUp FUNCTION */
/*******************/
int iDivUp(int a, int b) { return ((a % b) != 0) ? (a / b + 1) : (a / b); }

/*************************************************/
/* DEVICE FUNCTION PERFORMING THE SCALAR PRODUCT */
/*************************************************/
__host__ __device__ float scalarProduct(float p1x, float p1y, float p1z, float p2x, float p2y, float p2z)
{
    return (p1x * p2x + p1y * p2y + p1z * p2z) ;
}

/*******************/
/* KERNEL FUNCTION */
/*******************/
__global__ void kernel(const float* __restrict__ p1x, const float* __restrict__ p1y, const float* __restrict__ p1z, 
              const float* __restrict__ p2x, const float* __restrict__ p2y, const float* __restrict__ p2z, 
              float* __restrict__ output, const int N, const int M) {

    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int idy = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;

    if ((idx < N) && (idy < M))

        if(abs(scalarProduct(p1x[idx], p1y[idx], p1z[idx], p2x[idy], p2y[idy], p2z[idy])) < 0.01f) 
            output[idx] = 1.f;
        else
            output[idx] = 0.f;

}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    const int N = 10000;
    const int M = 1000;

    // --- Host side allocations
    float *Ax = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
    float *Ay = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
    float *Az = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));

    float *Bx = (float*)malloc(M*sizeof(float));
    float *By = (float*)malloc(M*sizeof(float));
    float *Bz = (float*)malloc(M*sizeof(float));

    float *C = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
    float *D = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));

    // --- Device side allocations
    float *d_Ax; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_Ax, N*sizeof(float)));
    float *d_Ay; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_Ay, N*sizeof(float)));
    float *d_Az; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_Az, N*sizeof(float)));

    float *d_Bx; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_Bx, M*sizeof(float)));
    float *d_By; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_By, M*sizeof(float)));
    float *d_Bz; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_Bz, M*sizeof(float)));

    float *d_C; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_C, N*sizeof(float)));

    // --- Initialization
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        Ax[i] = rand() / RAND_MAX;
        Ay[i] = rand() / RAND_MAX;
        Az[i] = rand() / RAND_MAX;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<M; i++) {
        Bx[i] = rand() / RAND_MAX;
        By[i] = rand() / RAND_MAX;
        Bz[i] = rand() / RAND_MAX;
    }

    // --- Host side computations
    double t1 = clock();
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) 
        for (int j=0; j<M; j++)
            if(abs(scalarProduct(Ax[i], Ay[i], Az[i], Bx[j], By[j], Bz[j])) < 0.01f) 
                C[i] = 1.f;
            else
                C[i] = 0.f;
    double t2 = clock();
    printf("CPU elapsed time: %3.4f ms \n", 1000.*((double)(t2-t1))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    // --- Device side computations
    float time;
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    // --- Host to device memory transfers
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_Ax, Ax, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_Ay, Ay, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_Az, Az, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_Bx, Bx, M*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_By, By, M*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_Bz, Bz, M*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // --- Computations
    kernel<<<iDivUp(N, BLOCKSIZE_X), BLOCKSIZE_X>>>(d_Ax, d_Ay, d_Az, d_Bx, d_By, d_Bz, d_C, N, M);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(D, d_C, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    printf("Elapsed time:  %3.4f ms \n", time);


    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        if (D[i] != C[i]) {
            printf("Mismatch at i = %i; Host= %f, Device = %f\n", i, C[i], D[i]);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    printf("Results match!\n");
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of optimising for arithmetic, you should use better algorithm first.
In most practical situation ts and A are not totally random per each cycle, and you may somehow organise (sort) them spatially, and greatly reduce the need for calculating spatial metric.

Now if you insist to stick with current algorithm, you may enable compiler to emit SSE code, this should give some instant boost without any programming work.

Now since you have to ask this question, the chance that you may further squeeze cycles by manually code with compiler intrinsics, is relatively narrow.

About CUDA, for just 10 million dot product the overhead for CPU-RAM-DISPLAY RAM-GPU communication is significant and not worth all the trouble.

Comment: Thanks, ts i uniformly distributed points on the sphere and A is just points on the sphere (almost random).

Answer (score 1):

To parallelize this using MIMD with OpenMP you can do this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i< ts.size(); i++){     
    for(int j = 0; j< A.size(); j++){
        if(abs(scalarProduct(ts.at(i), A.at(j))) <epsilon){
            score[i] +=1;
        }
    }
}
```

You could also consider using SIMD.  In that case you should change your data structure and store blocks of points equal to the SIMD width (4 for SSE with floats).  Something like

```
class PointBlock4 {
    float x[4];
    float y[4];
    float z[4];
    //
}
```

Each block has four points. This is obviously more complicated but it's achievable. You could get a speed up as four as well.  Combining SIMD and MIMD you could get a speedup of 16x (with four cores). But for large n your algorithm will become memory bound and not compute bound so you will achieve a much lower speedup. In fact your algorithm may already be memory bound so you might achieve much with SIMD or MIMD. I would test OpenMP first to see if you gain much.